# How to change notifyIcon1 icon in code

Tags: c#

This is what I have so far:

```
if (label1.Text == "On")
{
  notifyIcon1.Icon = Image.FromFile("@C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\On.ico");
}
```

What do I do make the icon equal to change it?

Comment: Are you using WPF, WinForms, something else?  What type is `notifyIcon1`?  What's wrong with what you've got so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work: Aside from the obvious, I put the @ before the quotes. It may not matter, just the way I do it.

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\On.ico");
```

You this helps you!